# Sending Get Request From Shopify

Tags: post, get, shopify, bluesnap

I want to send a get request from my Shopify store to a payment processor payment page (bluesnap).

I want when someone clicks on checkout button in the Cart page to be redirected to my Bluesnap payment page, but I also want the order total to be sent to Bluesnap payment page.

How do I can do that please?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I work for BlueSnap and would like to know about what you're trying to build.  Recently, Shopify has made it harder for merchants to use a gateway other than Shopify Payments, but if I know more I might be able to find a solution.

Comment: I already have bluesnap linked to myshopify store but Shopify checkout shows only credit card as a payment gateway, I have other payment methods in Bluesnap that I want to use. Therefore I want to use Bluesnap hosted payment page and integrate it with my store. I'm trying to follow this documentation https://support.bluesnap.com/docs/creating-a-hosted-payments-page

Answer (score 0):

This comes up from time to time. See [Shopify Plugin for making custom payement gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112054/shopify-plugin-for-making-custom-payement-gateway/49121478#49121478) for my discussion on options.